# Logistic regression probabilities in scikit-learn

Tags: probability, logistic, classification, multivariate-analysis, scikit-learn

When using logistic regression in Python's scikit-learn, one may handle multiclass problems even with binary logistic regression. If there are $K$ classes, then coefficients (i.e. weights and biases) for $K$ logistic functions will be produced. But this is using a 'one vs. rest' approach, and the probabilities from the individual logistic functions won't necessarily add up to 1 since this is binary logistic regression. Therefore, when using `predict_proba` with sklearn's logistic regression, how are probabilities handled in multiclass problems?

I've investigated this and it appears to be similar to applying a softmax function to the individual probabilities of the $K$ logistic functions, but this is not exactly correct. I also do not see explicit mention of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that, [they](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba) just apply simple normalization (i.e. divide by the sum of the probabilities) or softmax when `multi_class` option is set to `ovr` or `multinomial` respectively.

Comment: I had tested so many alternatives...yet somehow missed the simplest approach. Thank you. Although, is there any meaningful justification in applying the simple normalization they've used for the case of `ovr`? Since these are essentially from separately trained binary logistic classifiers, there doesn't appear to be any reason why the probabilities from the different models are valid for direct comparison.